# Want to use windows and Ubuntu in single Partition

Tags: installation, windows

I've Windows 8 in my PC, and want to Install Ubuntu 13 within same partition is it possible to use both the OS in single Partition

Comment: Why do you want to use the same partition?

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if you install Ubuntu within windows 7 using wubi.
But windows 8 has locked boot loader so it is not possible . That's why ubuntu 13.04 has removed wubi.

Comment: fine thanxs so its no mean to install Ubuntu within Windows 8